# Magento 2 missed PHP extensions

Tags: magento2, php, extensions

I'm trying to install magento's module, but it shows that I have missing PHP extensions. Sadly, it doesn't show which one is missing. I've activated all php extensions available in php.ini of my wamp64 server, but it didn't help. Do you know what should I be looking for? [image]

Comment: Please check system.log or exception.log file. We have one more option to check error like enable error_reporting in index.php file.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);